# How can I batch query on associations in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Lets's say I have a product model, a user model and a reviews model defined like this:

```
class Product
  has_many :reviews
end

class User
  has_many :reviews
end

class Review
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :model
end
```

Now in a controller method, I have a `current_user` variable. And I'm trying to get a list of products together with their reviews by the `current_user`.

Currently I'm doing something like this:

```
class ProductsController
  def index
    @products = Product.page(1)
  end
end

# in index.html.erb

<%= @products.each do |product| %>
  <%= product.reviews.find_by(user: current_user).rating %>
<% end %>
```

But it's generating one SQL query for each `product.reviews.find_by` call. Is there anyway I could avoid this?

I tried modifying code in controller to:

```
class ProductsController
  def index
    @products = Product.page(1).include(:reviews)
  end
end
```

which doesn't work. Am I using it wrongly?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use it like this

```
# controller
@products = Product.includes(:reviews).page(1)

# view
<%= @products.each do |product| %>
  <%= product.reviews.select{ |user| user.id == current_user.id }.rating %>
<% end %>
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations

Edit:
You can filter on the includes too like this for performance

```
@products = Product.includes(:reviews).where("reviews.user_id" => 1).page(1)
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Just a nit: `detect` should be used here instead of `select`. Actually, according to my sample code, it should be: `product.reviews.detect { |review| review.user_id == current_user.id }`

Comment: Sorry but allow me to ask another question, will this cause any performance issue if the product has a really big number of reviews?

Comment: However, since you're fetching it by page, it will only fetch the reviews that belong to those items.